# Why are the league tables not dynamically updated?

Tags: discussion

What I can see is, the [league tables](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/) are updated only at the end of the day, and not dynamically. Why is this so? Can this be improved?

Comment: It's probably an expensive query which makes sense to do only once per day.

Comment: Why do you need the league table updated more often?  Do you need to know that you are ranked 23,225 or 23,224 immediately?

Answer (score 0):

League tables are not updated dynamically because of the huge memory it takes. But, if someone wants to see their new position, they may go to [users tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users) which is updated dynamically, though it could be a little difficult if you are above 1000!